# How do I sort nodes in node_view_multiple()?

Tags: 7, views, nodes, blocks

I created a block with node teasers loaded with `node_view_multiple($nodes)`.

Now I want to order the results:

- By Node ID
- By the time is was created/updated
- Random

Of course I can order them with PHP array functions, but is there a Drupal specific way to do it?

Comment: The ordering should be done by whatever is loading the nodes (i.e. the database query)

Comment: @Clive so in case of `node_view_multiple()` I should hook to `entity_prepare_view`, right?

Comment: That'll be too late, you'll end up having to do it in php which is inefficient - you need to hook into the build of the database query itself. Where is the data coming from?

Comment: @Clive data comes from `node_load_multiple`, that loads an array of nids from the settings form.

Comment: That's probably where you want to do the sorting: to the original array of node IDs you pass to node_load_multiple. That should be most efficient I think

Comment: Clive is correct. The NIDs should be sorted before calling node_load_multiple(), ideally within the original query that retrieves them in the first place, but if not, then using PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I can think of to do this is using EntityFieldQuery:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
  $entities = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->propertyCondition('type', 'your_type')
    ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
    ->propertyOrderBy('nid', 'ASC')
    ->propertyOrderBy('changed', 'DESC')
    ->addTag('random') //this gets the query passed through hook_query_alter
    ->execute();
```

And you will need hook_query_alter to do the random sort because EFQ doesn't do that natively

```
function icac_custom_query_random_alter(QueryAlterableInterface $query) {
  $query->orderRandom();
}
```

To get the nid's for node_load_multiple

```
$nids = array_keys($entities['node']);
```

Comment: You wouldn't believe, I used EXACTLY the same code! Where were you before? :) Thanks, anyway.